# Does an ssh server necessarily support sftp?

Tags: ssh, sftp

Every sshd server I have ever connected to supports sftp. However, is this necessarily the case? Or are there notable exceptions?

I am asking because many shared hosting accounts offer "ssh accounts" that by default only offer sftp server (they have an empty shell for interactive sessions).

If the answer is yes, then it would make sense that programs like `ssh-copy-id` use sftp instead of ssh to transfer keys because that would be the more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

No. The `sftp` in SSH servers is just non-mandatory subsystem (but quite widely supported, because it is more user-friendly and provides much better performance than the simple `scp`).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have that feeling because most Linux-based systems do enable that feature in their config by default after installing the SSH server package, but it's not mandatory, as @Jakuje said, it's just a feature but it can be disabled.

In the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file there is a directive like this:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Simply commenting it out would disable the SFTP feature.